# React native firebase, user name not updated on registration

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, native

In my application I am using React native with firebase.

I used `createUserWithEmailAndPassword( auth,email,password)` function with `updateProfile()` within it to update the name and then redirect to homepage. I want to display name on home page after creating user successfully. It doesn't show name on home page after registration, however it shows name when I login and redirect to same homepage, or re-save my code. here is my homescreen.

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { signOutEmail } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  console.log

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{user.displayName}</Text>
      <View style={[styles.container, { margin: 15 }]}></View>
      <Button title="Setting" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("setting")} />
      <Button title="Sign Out" onPress={() => signOutEmail()} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

this is my first question ever on any website so excuse me if I am unable to explain it properly

I tried to log user on homepage after registering it got user with displayName:undefined, but works after login properly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like calling `updateProfile` only updates the profile on the server, and does not immediately update the profile in your application. If that is the case, you can call [`reload` on the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload) in your code to force it to reload.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it didn't work. However I have found a way around

Comment: @AlexAung: as said in the answer, you can call [`reload` on the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload) to force their profile to load the latest values from the server.